# Quickbooks online oauth 2.0 not able to load tax code using php

Tags: php, api, quickbooks-online, tax, rates

Quick book online oauth 2.0 not able to load tax code using following query.

```
$TaxRateService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxRate();
$taxRates = $TaxRateService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM TaxRate WHERE Id IN('$id')");
```

I am using IPP v3

Comment: What programming language is that? Please tag your question accordingly

Comment: using php quickbook API Library

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? What does the XML you're getting back from QuickBooks look like?

Comment: We first get the taxcode from quickbooks using following query:-
$TaxCodeService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxCode();
and then get the tax rates for each tax code using the following query
$TaxRateService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_TaxRate();
But It returns NULL and we are not getting any tax rates for the tax codes